# Is $2 = 123$ modulo $6$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is $2 = 123$  modulo $6$?

How do I attack this question?

Do I just answer: What is $123$ MOD $6$? The answer is 3.

So: Is $2 = 123$  modulo $6$? Answer is NO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the phrase "$a=b$ (mod $n$)" is shorthand for, "$a-b$ is a multiple of $n$." In this case, you don't even have to calculate ${121\over 6}$ - if $a=2$ (mod $6$), then $a$ had better be even; do you see why?

Comment: Excellent, that was very clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Is $123-2=121$ divisible by $6$?

Comment: Is that what the question is really asking or are you asking me a rhetorical question? Based on your question, the answer is no. Is that true?

Comment: @lucidgold This is precisely what the question is asking. Plug in to your calculator $121/6$. Do you get a whole number?

Comment: Right, thank you for that, I have a lot to learn. I have upvoted your answer.